# Laravel Eloquent Model Relationships fetching

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel, I have articles and Users table. How do i fetch who's user created a specific  article

All articles

1. Article 1 by John Doe
2. Article 3 by Jane Doe.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [relationships docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships):

```
$article = Article::where('id','=',10)->with('user')->first();

echo "article {$article->id} by {$article->user->name}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a relation method to your `Article` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Then you can access to this user by a magic method with the property of `user` like this:

```
{{ $article->user->email }}
```